# Miniterm not showing valid output when working with NodeMCU

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, nodemcu

I am trying to use miniterm to execute Lua commands on my NodeMCU. I don't think there's any problem with my chip or cable because I can code the chip using Arduino IDE. While using miniterm, I believe we are supposed to get a interactive command prompt, but I never get that. Some articles have suggested pressing the ENTER button or resetting the NodeMCU, but that hasn't worked as well. I believe I have successfully installed the USB to UART CP2102 driver (from Silicons Lab). Any suggestions as to what else I can do?

This is my 'miniterm.py' command output. The unknown symbols continue whenever I press the ENTER key...

```
--- Available ports:
---  1: /dev/ttyUSB0         'CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller'
--- Enter port index or full name: 1
--- Miniterm on /dev/ttyUSB0  9600,8,N,1 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H
---␒�␒␀��K �1��a���0,␞�`!␐�(␀�␂�␅�  �lO␇�`�bFa���␑␖5��������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Miniterm to use 115'200bps instead of 9600bps.

See https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload/

> The NodeMCU serial interface uses 115'200bps at boot time. To change the speed after booting, issue `uart.setup(0,9600,8,0,1,1)`. If the device panics and resets at any time, errors will be written to the serial interface at 115'200 bps.

The gibberish you see are the SDK bootloader messages which come at 74'880bps.

Comment: Glad it was useful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work